# issue with .htaccess using 301 Redirection with params

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to stop parameters from getting appeneded to url

issue with .htaccess i have website say example.com

**1: i have to redirect**

example.com/deatils.php?366%2520WORDS%2520IN%2520MUMBAI example.com/bookshelf/366_words_in_mumbai

i wrote below code

```
RewriteRule ^deatils.php?366%2520WORDS%2520IN%2520MUMBAI example.com/bookshelf/366_words_in_mumbai [R=301,L]
```

but opening 
example.com/deatils.php?366%2520WORDS%2520IN%2520MUMBAI

redirect to example.com/bookshelf/366_words_in_mumbai?366%252520WORDS%252520IN%252520MUMBAI

i do not want strings after "?" to be appened

Answer (score 0):

Use this additional rule for the redirection in your htaccess and it will work for you.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)366%2520WORDS%2520IN%2520MUMBAI($|&)
RewriteRule ^deatils\.php$ /bookshelf/366_words_in_mumbai? [L,R=301]
```